# Does the order of a class on a selector matter? If yes, can I specify the ordering?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a difference between:

```
<span id="test" class="one two"></span>
```

and

```
<span id="test" class="two one"></span>
```

If there are conflicting CSS rules on these classes does the order matter?

Are there any APIs in jQuery to reorder?  When I call `addClass()` does it always go on the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order doesn't matter.

http://jsfiddle.net/rc8Yu/

[css precedence](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)

The important part here is

> If two rules are equal in all of the above, the one declared last wins. CSS embedded in the html always come after external stylesheets regardless of the order in the html

Answer (score 3):

The order of the classes in HTML doesn't not matter, but the order *inside the CSS* does matter. For example, if you had:

```css
span.one { color: red }
span.two { color: blue }
```

Both spans with `class="one two"` and `class="two one"` would produce blue text, because the class "two" is defined last. But if we changed that to

```css
span.two { color: blue }
span.one { color: red }
```

and did the same thing, both spans would now have red text because the class "one" is defined last. Also keep in mind that the ID will override both of those classes no matter what, so if I defined:

```css
span#test { color: green }
```

and added `id="test"`, then the spans will always have green text no matter where in the document the classes and ID selector are defined, because an ID is naturally more specific than a class (other instances can make a class more specific than an ID, etc).

---

Since this is true, the order of your classes as assigned by jQuery is completely irrelevant. You should not need to worry about reordering them, but yes, addClass does just add the class to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If using the `classList` DOM property, then the order is significant.

The object returned has the classes set as numeric properties; ascending order as the class names from left to right.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7a4Bu/).

Comment: And any classes added with `addClass` would be appended to the end of the list.